# Why does "use" not work when included in php?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm updating my apps to work with the new PHP SDK, but I'm having this issue:
I want to do the Facebook stuff in a separate php file to keep things clean.
For example, this is my fb.php page:

```
<?php
require_once('sdk/autoload.php');

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(...,...);

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new session from saved access_token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

    // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
    try {
        if ( !$session->validate() ) {
            $session = null;
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // catch any exceptions
        $session = null;
    }
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

    // save the session
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
    // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
    $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

//logged in

} else {

    //user is not logged in
    ?>
    <script>window.location="...link to login page...";</script>
<?php
    exit;
}
```

A page which uses the Facebook session, could look like this (testing.php):

```
<?php
require_once('fb.php');

$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

echo "Welcome, ".$graphObject['first_name'];
```

This returns this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found

The code works fine when I put `use Facebook\FacebookRequest;` in testing.php , but I don't want to do that, since that was the point of putting all the Facebook session stuff in a separate fb.php file...

What is the reason for this, and is there a solution how to keep all my Facebook stuff in a separate file?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you move `$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );` from your testing.php to the fb.php ?  Can you access it in testing.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File in which you are including `fb.php` is in different scope so can't use that imports.
You have to specify them again.

You can read more about that [in PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).